# jQuery datepicker UI getdate() - How do I just output date only and NOT Wed Oct 06 2010 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently this code is working but not as expected:

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(_date, _datepicker)
        {
            var myDate = new Date(_date);
            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+8);
            $('#estimated_hatching_date').text(myDate);
            alert( myDate);       
        }

        });
```

The first issue is, how the date is presented.  Currently that code above alerts **Fri Oct 01 2010 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)**.  I would like the output to be just the date, for example, 09/06/2010.

The second issue is, **$('#estimated_hatching_date').text(myDate);** does not change the text.  When that code is fired nothing is changed.  However if I do: **$('#estimated_hatching_date').text('myDate');** myDate is placed into the #estimated_hatching_date div.

So, how do I just output the date and replace the "text" inside of #estimated_hatching_date div with just the date +7 days from when a date is selected?

Thank You,
     Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI Datepicker has a built in [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function.  Please @dottedquad, don't use your self-made version, date math and formatting is harder than you imagine.  The corner cases will make you tear your hair out.

```
onSelect: function(_date, _datepicker) {
    var myDate = new Date(_date);
    var myText = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy',myDate);
    alert(myText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read over the ui datepicker manual again and figured it out.

```
    $("#start_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(_date, _datepicker)
    {
        var myDate = new Date(_date);
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+8);
        var fullYear = myDate.getFullYear();
        var month = ((myDate.getMonth()+1) < 10) ? ('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)) : myDate.getMonth()+1;
        var day = (myDate.getDate() < 10) ? ('0' + myDate.getDate()) : myDate.getDate();
        var myNewDate = fullYear + '-' + day + '-' + month;

        $('#estimated_hatching_date').text(myNewDate);
        alert(myNewDate);
    }
    });
```

That code works as expected.  Anyone else have any more ideas that would get that job done differently?

-Thank You,
     Rich

Comment: Thank you for that tip.  I'll have to test that out :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used "altField" option with a hidden input. Hidden input's value is always formatted according to "dateFormat"